# How to display node details and call function in *.html.twig

Tags: 8, nodes

I work in D8, I create a custom module first_module. By modules create a url and display all nodes by *.html.twig file.

Write code in controller.php

```
public function contentthree() {

  $connection = Database::getConnection();

  $query = $connection->select('node', 'n');
  $query->fields('n', ['nid', 'type']);

  $groups = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $events[] = [$group->nid, $group->type];
  }

  return [
    '#theme'  => 'first_module_display',
    '#events' => $events,
  ];
}
```

In *.module

```
function first_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return [
    'first_module_display' => [
      'variables' => ['events' => NULL],
      'template'  => 'first-module-list',
    ],
  ];
}

function _get_node_details() {

  $output = 'Welcome D8';

  $output .= 'Node Details';

  return $output;
}
```

and create templates first-module-list.html.twig and display data

```
{%for key, data in events %}

{%for key1, data1 in data %}

   {{ data1 }}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

work fine and showing data correct. But, my question is how to call `function _get_node_details()` and how to render node details in `first-module-list.html.twig` files?

Comment: This is not the right approach. Before tackling a module like this I suggest you spend more time familiarising yourself with the documentation. You should not be working directly with DB connections for a start.

Comment: I agree with @AlfredArmstrong about becoming more familiar with more some of the site building techniques (views) with Drupal as it helps make your site more maintainable. I disagree that using DBTNG is wrong and that may be necessary. For your specific question about rendering text returned from _get_node_details(), you can add to your controller's returned render array with #markup. Additionally your global functions should also be prefixed with the module name.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would have implemented this feature differently. Let me just answer the specific question, and then I will tell you an alternative approach.

#### Custom 'functions' in Twig

The easiest thing for you could be to [Implement a twig macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html).

However, macros could be limiting. To have all the PHP power you can create a [*twig extension function*](https://medium.com/@thihathit/extending-custom-twig-extension-to-drupal-8-twig-extension-class-d4b99c2177ae)

If you are in a rush and are into bad practices, then there is the [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) *php filter*, so that you can do this:

```
<div class="bad-practice">
     {{ 'return _get_node_details();'|php }} 
</div>
```

#### Alternative implementation using Drupal views

- Create a Drupal View, with a Block Display.
- Place the new Block, using the Block Layout.
- If you need to do a heavy alteration use a [hook_views_data_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter).